# A simple group-by (no count) in Django

Tags: sql, django

If this were raw-SQL, it'd be a no-brainer, but in Django, this is proving to be quite difficult to find.  What I want is this really:

```
SELECT
  user_id
FROM
  django_comments
WHERE
  content_type_id = ? AND
  object_pk = ?
GROUP BY
  user_id
```

It's those last two lines that're the problem.  I'd like to do this the "Django-way" but the only thing I've found is mention of aggregates and annotations, which I don't think solve this issue... do they?  If someone could explain this to me, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can see you want to have the authors of all comments of a specific [GenericObject](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) (say Article).

Djangos ORM offers following of [relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)
So the solution would be:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

User.objects.filter(comment_comments__content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label="articles", model="article"), comment_comments__object_pk="12").distinct()
```

if you like to have the users id, use things like values_list or values

```
User.objects.filter(comment_comments__content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label="articles", model="article"), comment_comments__object_pk="12").distinct().values_list('id')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, though to me, it still seems way more complicated than SQL.  Thanks for the tip, it works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a no-brainer in Django as well, but you need to stop thinking in terms of SQL and instead ask yourself what you actually want to achieve.

"I want a list of all user IDs who have posted comments." Well then, that's what you ask for:

```
 Comment.objects.filter(
    content_type_id=foo, object_pk=bar
 ).values_list('user_id', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: Well that sort of works.  It returned a list of user ids alright, but it didn't group them at all:

Comment.objects.all().filter(content_type=48, object_pk="88").values_list('user_id', flat=True)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: Sorry, needed to add `distinct`. Updated.

Comment: I tried that too, still no joy.  I assume that the .distinct() s working on the assumption that it's comparing all values in the table and not just user_id.  But yes, even with .distinct() the result is a list of identical user ids.